# How to access static data across microservices?

Tags: java, static, hashmap, microservices

I have a common class in which I am having a static map as :

```
private static Map<String,List<Logging>> loggingResponseMap ;
public static Map<String, List<Logging>> getLoggingResponseMap() {
        return Logging.loggingResponseMap;
    }

    public static void setLoggingResponseMap(Map<String, List<Logging>> loggingResponseMapObj) {
        Logging.loggingResponseMap = loggingResponseMapObj;
    }
```

I am setting the value in this map in one micrservice and trying to access it in other microservice but instead of getting the data I am getting null in other other microservice.
What could be the reason ?? Is it possible to access the static map across microservice ?
Thanks

Comment: where are you setting the value?  you are setting an un initialized variable. If you have code to load data to loggingResponseMapObj you have to invoke the same in other services.

Comment: @JishnuPrathap I am loading the data in one of the microservice , and in that microservice I can see the data but when I am trying to access the same data from other microservice it is giving null.

Comment: Tell us the actual use case you are trying to achieve we might be able provide suggestions

Comment: @JishnuPrathap actual use case is I want to set some logging information from one service and make it accessible from other microservice . Hence , I thought of using some static variable because I can't use instance variable as instance variable will make the direct dependency on the classes.

Answer (score 1):

No, you will not be able to access any variables, not just static variables, of one microservice in an another microservice. This is not specific to spring-boot, it is the same for any java program. You will have to load the data to the variable separately in each service.

If you are looking to avoid repeated code to the load data in each microservice, you can move the code to a common program and add the common program as as dependency in all the microservices where you want to load the data.